# Confused by foldLeft error (both in Eclipse and REPL)

Tags: scala

The context for this is pretty simple. My assumptions are based on Odersky's book "Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition", section 8.5 describing "Placeholder Syntax".

I have a List[List[Boolean]] (i.e. a rectangular bit map) where I am attempting to count the total occurrences of the value "true". Here's the REPL line defining the data which executes fine:

```
val rowsByColumns =
    List(   List(false, true, false)
          , List(true, true, true)
          , List(false, true, false)
        )
```

Next, I attempted to count the occurrences of "true" with the following line. And instead of executing, I receive an error:

```
val marks = (for(row <- rowsByColumns)
    yield {row.foldLeft[Int](0)(_ + (if (_) 1 else 0))}).sum

<console>:8: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2
       val marks = (for(row <- rowsByColumns) yield {row.foldLeft[Int](0)(_ + (i
f (_) 1 else 0))}).sum
                                                                        ^
```

I did not understand the error as I have the two underscores representing the parameters to the function. So, I made the function more explicit by writing this which executes just fine:

```
val marks = (for(row <- rowsByColumns)
      yield {row.foldLeft[Int](0)((sum, marked) => sum + (if (marked) 1 else 0))}
    ).sum
```

My question is this: Why did I receive and error for the less explicit case, but when I map out the function by reducing the "simplifications", it executes correctly?

Thank you for any insight you can give me on this.

Comment: Given further thought about this, is there any chance that Odersky's proposal (in some SIP) to alter Scala's syntax to do away with the required parenthesis in the if's evaluation expression would correct his "defect" such that reimplementing the original erred statement by removing the parenthesis from the if would make it work correctly?

Comment: Here's the document (SIP-12 Uncluttering Scala Syntax - Part 1: if) to which I was referring: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/uncluttering-control.html

Comment: The two language design questions (parentheses for conditions and limits on placeholder syntax) are orthogonal—the relationship between parentheses and binding of underscores is just a rule of thumb, as you can see from an example like `val f: Boolean => Int = if (_) 1 else 0`, where the parentheses _don't_ bind the underscore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The limitations of Scala's placeholder syntax for anonymous functions can be extremely confusing (to me, at least). One rule of thumb is that underscores get bound to their nearest enclosing parentheses, but this is an approximation—see section 6.23 of [the Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for the detail:

> An expression *e* of syntactic category `Expr` *binds* an underscore
>   section *u*, if the following two conditions hold: (1) *e* properly
>   contains *u*, and (2) there is no other expression of syntactic
>   category `Expr` which is properly contained in *e* and which itself
>   properly contains *u*.

In this case the compiler doesn't see the second underscore as a second parameter. This might seem odd, since `_ + _` is properly seen as having two parameters, and `if (_) x else y` is equivalent to `z => if (z) x else y` (where `z` is a fresh identifier), but nesting the two doesn't work.

It's true that the compiler *could* in theory figure out that the two underscores should be parameters for the same anonymous function in your `foldLeft`, but not, for example, in the following, where the second underscore really does need to be bound separately:

```
rowsByColumns.map(_.map(!_))
```

This would require a lot of extra cleverness on the part of the compiler, though, and the Scala language designers have decided that it's not worth it—that placeholder syntax only needs to be provided for some fairly simple cases without nested expressions.

---

Luckily in this case you can just write `rowsByColumns.flatten.count(identity)` instead. `flatten` here concatenates the sublists to give a single `List[Boolean]`. We then want to know how many of the values in that list are `true`. `count` takes a predicate and tells you how many values in a collection satisfy that predicate. For example, here's one way to count the even numbers between 1 and 10 (inclusive):

```
val isEven: Int => Boolean = _ % 2 == 0    
(1 to 10) count isEven
```

In your case, though, we already have boolean values, so the predicate doesn't need to do any work—it can just be the identity function `x => x`. As dhg notes in a comment, Scala's [`Predef` object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef%24.html) provides this as a method named `identity`, which I'm using here. You could just as easily write `rowsByColumns.flatten.count(x => x)`, though, if you find that clearer.

Comment: Similar to dhg's response, I've read and re-read your answer and still don't get it. I am still not seeing how the mis-interpretation is occurring, although I have this vague sense that the parenthesis have two meanings; firstly a mathematical meaning (to set precedence within a set of operator relationships) and secondly as a means to define a Scala function literal. And as I said to dhg, even in this context, why isn't the compiler back-tracking upon the error and re-evaluating the expression to make more sense of it (given that to me, the resulting function literal is nonsense).

Comment: As to your very last sentence - I didn't understand it. I don't know what "identity" is. I used Scalax.org to find quite a few reverences to identity, but couldn't tell what it meant. Would you mind giving me a more English explanation of what it does. I think get the flatten part, but not the count nor identity parts.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium, `identity` is just a predefined function that means `x => x`

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium, I've updated the answer. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: @Travis Very nice. Tyvm. At least I now understand the conflict on the parethesis and the placeholder syntax.

Comment: @Travis My confusion around your using "identity" is why would you use the placeholder (replacing "idenitity") in count? IOW, why wouldn't you do rowsByColumns.flatten.count(_)? I've now played with this in REPL and now see that using the underscore does something not intuitive to me; it didn't return 5. It returned "res2: ((Boolean) => Boolean) => Int = <function1>" Huh?!

Answer (score 3):

We can examine your question by looking at a simpler case:

```
(0 to 1).map(x => if(x > 1) 1 else 0)  // fine
(0 to 1).map(if(_ > 1) 1 else 0)       // error
```

There error we see is

```
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$greater(1))
              (0 to 1).map(if(_ > 1) 1 else 0)
                              ^
```

So what's happening is that Scala is expanding `_` into `(x$1) => x$1` at the narrowest possible scope.  In other words, it's trying to do:

```
(0 to 1).map(if((x) => x > 1) 1 else 0)
```

but this is wrong.

Your case is similar.  The two `_` are not treated as both being in the same scope, which is why it thinks there's only one parameter.  The second `_` is expanded inside the scope of the `if`, which is wrong.  It thinks you are doing this:

```
row.foldLeft[Int](0)((x) => x + (if ((y) => y) 1 else 0))
```

Comment: But note that `List(true, false).map(if (_) 1 else 0)` is just fine. The problem isn't the parentheses in the `if` condition.

Comment: @dhg I'm still confused, even after reading your answer several times. I am not seeing the use in an expansion of ...(if ((y) => y) 1 else 0)). And even if it is doing that expansion which results in an error, why isn't the compiler backtracking to re-interpret it in a way that more consistently follows the "referential transparency" notion of anywhere an expression exists, it can be replaced by its return value?

Answer (score 1):

> Given further thought about this, is there any chance that Odersky's proposal ([in SIP 12](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/uncluttering-control.html?_ga=1.215761823.948393304.1470074846)) to alter Scala's syntax to do away with the required parenthesis in the if's evaluation expression would correct his "defect" such that reimplementing the original erred statement by removing the parenthesis from the if would make it work correctly

Note (August 216, 4 years later): the decision is

> ### Postponed To A Future Release
>
> This SIP is in Postponed status currently, with the current action for 2.10.
>
> - (1) Deprecate "`then`" in identifiers to reserve for future keyword status.
> - (2) Deprecate problematic "`while() do`" syntax. ("`do`" loops in while loops require braces).
>
> Originally proposed in 2011, the proposal suggested syntax changes in `if`’s, `for` and `while` loops, moving Scala’s syntax away from Java and C-like languages.
>   Whereas such changes may be arguably more beautiful, the Committee agreed that would give more problems than benefits.

See [issue 555](https://github.com/scala/scala.github.com/issues/555)