# Anonymous function pecularities

Tags: scala, anonymous-function, iterable

I am puzzled by the difference between

```
Array(true,false).filter(x=>x).map(println(_))

(runs fine)
```

and

```
Array(true,false).filter(_).map(println(_))

(throws error)
```

Notice the filter arguments: `x=>x` versus `_`. I was under the expression that `x=>x` and `_` were synonymous. How to explain this?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365499/334519) for some discussion (and references) about the issues you've run into here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you running `.map(println(_))`? Don't think it's a good idea to map something to a list of side-effects.

Comment: @KChaloux I used a side-effect to show in repl what was being filtered.

Comment: @Dominykas the Repl will print out your result for you, generally. The only time you'll be in trouble is when you have a _lot_ of values and the Repl truncates them with an ellipsis. In any case, for side-effectful printing to stuff, you probably want `.foreach(println(_))` (or just `foreach println _`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter(_)` is desugared into `x => filter(x)`. Look to your map usage: `map(println(_))`, it is desugared into `map(x => println(x))` but not into `map(println(x => x))`, that not right and wont work