# Scala underscore syntax and higher order functions

Tags: scala, syntax, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

I'm having a hard time understanding the scala compiler here. I'm passing three higher order functions to a superclass like this:

```
... extends Arithmetic(Math.pow(-_,_), Math.log(_)/Math.log(_), Math.pow(_,_))
```

The first function doesn't compile, the last function compiles, the only difference being the minus sign. The compiler gives the following warning:

```
error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 2
```

which is confusing, as there are two underscores. I will probably have to ditch the underscore syntax, but I want to understand why this happens. I have also tried

```
Math.pow(0-(_),_)    Math.pow(0.-(_),_)    Math.pow(0.0.-(_),_)
```

which all give the same error. Finally

```
Math.pow(-(_:Double),_:Double)
```

gives a new error

```
error: type mismatch;
  found   : Double => Double
  required: Double
```

which looks more like an actual error instead of me violating syntax. Now my next thought was, "apparently the underscore syntax doesn't work if there are functions within others". But looking at the second function `Math.log(_) / Math.log(_)`, which to my knowledge is converted to `Math.log(_)./(Math.log(_))`, and compiles, this makes no sense, as here the partially applied `log` function is passed into `./(...)`

Also, the expected type of the function, defined in the superclass `Arithmetic` is `(Double,Double) => Double`, so why does the type problem only surface after I explicitely declared the types?

Color me confused.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365499/334519) for some discussion.

Comment: it's even a problem for calls of arity one: `var f1: Function1[Double,Double] = _` will allow `f1 = Math.sqrt(_) * 3` but `f1 = Math.sqrt(_ * 3)` gives `error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$times(3))` (though `f1 = x => Math.sqrt(x * 3)` works just fine)

Comment: @RobStarling `val f: Double => Double = math sqrt _ * 3`.

Comment: Travis could have added that this is a dupe. Instead of the close mechanism, SO should aggregate dupes to maximize chances of a search succeeding, then redirect to the most correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.pow(_,_)` means `(x,y) => Math.pow(x,y)` whereas `Math.pow(-_,_)` means `y => Math.pow(x => -x,y)`. `Math.log(_)/Math.log(_)` is an infix method call, it means the same as `Math.log(_)./(Math.log(_))` and therefore `(x,y) => Math.log(x)./(Math.log(y))`.

See the [StackOverflow Scala Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) in Chapter 21 "Functions/Function literals" and the subpoints "Placeholder syntax" to find more detailed explanations about how the underscores are parsed.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't `Math.log(_)/Math.log(_)` then mean `y => Math.log(y)./(x => Math.log(x))` by the same logic? Why does this work?

Comment: It works because it is infix notation. See my update.